# Assertion through Django restApi

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to insert records through APIView but it returns error like
**Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`**

this is views.py

```
class TrackList(APIView):
def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    employee = Employee.objects.filter(username=kwargs.get('username'), password=kwargs.get('password'))        
    if employee.exists():
        serializer_class = TrackSerializer(data = request.data)
        try:
            if serializer_class.is_valid():
                serializer_class.save(employee=employee[0])
                return response.Response(serializer_class.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return response.Response(serializer_class.errors, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

please help me how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

When `employee.exists() == False` or `serializer_class.is_valid() == False`, then the execution moves to the end of the method, where it implicitly returns `None`.

Fix it with the following. When the employee doens't exist, it will return a Not Found response with a 404 status. When the serializer data is not valid, it will return an empty response with a 400 Bad Request status.

```
class TrackList(APIView):
def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    employee = Employee.objects.filter(username=kwargs.get('username'), password=kwargs.get('password'))        
    if employee.exists():
        serializer_class = TrackSerializer(data = request.data)
        try:
            if serializer_class.is_valid():
                serializer_class.save(employee=employee[0])
                return response.Response(serializer_class.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return response.Response(serializer_class.errors, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        return response.Response(None, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return response.Response(None, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```